# Conversion from millimeter to km (with overflow in smaller units e.g. m)

Tags: c++

I need to write a program in C++ that converts mm units to km, m, cm and mm. On input of 7580341 mm it should output `7580341mm equals 7km 580m 34cm 1mm`. I'm getting `7km 6m 34cm 1mm` instead. I did something wrong with the modulo function. Why does it calculate correct values with cm and mm, but not with m?

```
int mm, cm, m, km;
cout << "Type in value in millimeter:\n";
cin >> mm;

cm = mm/10;
m = mm/1000;
km = mm/1000000;

cout << mm << "mm equals " << km << "km " << m%km << "m " << cm%m << "cm " << mm%cm << "mm\n";

return 0;
```

Comment: You're not using the modulo operator `%` right. Read up about what it does.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to convet for meters :

```
double convert(string str){ 
string numb;
for(int i=0; i<str.length()-2; i++){
    if ((str[i]>='0'&& str[i]<='9')||(str[i]='.')){
        numb+=str[i];
    }
}
int pos=str.length();
char const* n=numb.c_str();
double result = strtod(n, NULL);

if((str[pos-2]=='T')) // Terra
    return result*(1e+12);
else if((str[pos-2]=='G')) //Giga
    return result*(1e+9);
else if((str[pos-2]=='M')) //Mega
    return result*(1e+6);
else if((str[pos-2]=='k')) //kilo
    return result*(1e+3);
else if((str[pos-2]=='d')) //decimetre
    return result*(1e-1);
else if((str[pos-2]=='c')) //centimetre
    return result*(1e-2);
else if((str[pos-2]=='m')) //millimetre
    return result*(1e-3);
else if((str[pos-2]=='μ')) //micrometre
    return result*(1e-6);
else if((str[pos-2]=='n')) //nanometre
    return result*(1e-9);
else if((str[pos-2]=='p')) //picometre
    return result*(1e-12);
else 
    return -1; //if is false .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening since you don't "remove" the parts you've assigned to each unit.

If you know that it's e.g. 7 km, then the millimeters that made up those kilometers need to be removed from the total count of millimeters, otherwise you're going to "use" them again.

So, do:

```
const int km = mm / 1000000;
if(km > 0)
  mm -= 1000000 * km;
```

and so on. You can also use the `%` modulo operator:

```
const int km = mm / 1000000;
mm %= 1000000;
```

Comment: He attempts to remove it in the `cout` line, but the code is just flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi need to use modulo operator

Something like this

```
km = mm/1000000;
m = (mm%1000000)/1000;
cm = ((mm%1000000)%1000)/10;
mm = ((mm%1000000)%1000)%10;
```